# simple regex for name validation

Tags: regex

Trying to do a simple name validation for an input field.  I do not need a list on what fails and what passes.

What I am trying to do is :

- the entire input can be nothing (0) or a max of 32 total
- if something is entered it must start with a character
- anything after one character it can contain any combination of [a-z '-.,]

The max doesn't appear to be working and it is failing on 0 and 1 character entered.  I've always been bad with these as they don't come up much for me.  Tried quite a few things.

```
/^([a-z]+[a-z '-.,]*){0,32}$/i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` in regex means "repeat the previous character one or more times," `*` means "repeat the previous character zero or more times," and `{0, 32}` means "repeat the previous character zero to 32 times." Therefore `([a]+[b]*){0,32}` repeats a repetition followed by a repetition.

I think the regex you want is

```
/^[a-z][a-z '-.,]{0,31}$|^$/i
```

Explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/jG1mS4):

- 1st Alternative: `^[a-z][a-z '-.,]{0,31}$`

  - `^` assert position at start of the string
  - `[a-z]` match a single character present in the list below

    - `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
  - `[a-z '-.,]{0,31}` match a single character present in the list below

    - `Quantifier`: Between 0 and 31 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    - `a-z` a single character in the range between `a` and `z` (case insensitive)
    - `<space>` the literal character `<space>`
    - `'-.` a single character in the range between `'` and `.`
    - `,` the literal character `,`
  - `$` assert position at end of the string
- 2nd Alternative: `^$`

  - `^` assert position at start of the string
  - `$` assert position at end of the string

Comment: 31 or 32 - you are using both. Typo? and yay! for Regex101.com!

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to say 31.

Comment: I think there is still some confusion. The match should be valid for zero characters as well.

Comment: @Floris `^$` matches zero characters

Comment: Sorry - had not seen the last part. Must be going blind. You still have a `32` in the explanation...

Comment: @Floris It attempts to match the string to _either_ `^[a-z][a-z '-.,]{0,31}$` _or_ `^$`.

Comment: @Floris And I'm going blind too, because I missed those `32`s. XD

Comment: @RyanCarlson, I wouldn't say that `[a-z]` is case-*in*sensitive; it will match all characters in the (for simplicity's sake, let's say: ASCII) range between 'a' (dec:97/hex:61) and 'z' (dec:122/hex:7A); which is the lower-case letters of the English alphabet.  
To match the English letters of lower and upper case, you would use a character class of `[a-zA-Z]`, which will match on characters in either of those ranges.

Comment: @RyanCarlson - Whoops, I missed that. Sorry/Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working as expected. I changed this to `/^[a-z][a-z .,\-]{0,31}$|^$/i` though as I wanted the literal space, period, comma, and hyphen allowed.  Thanks

Comment: @user756659 No problem, I like helping people! I wondered whether you wanted the literal character `-` or not, but I (incorrectly) assumed that you wanted all characters between `'` and `,`.